# Boot from sdcard

Tags: internal-storage, huawei

I did something to my phone(Huawei Ascend Y550-L01) and now it displays:

[image: Error]

The internal storage is probably dead. So I had this idea. Maybe I can boot from the sdcard? If it's possible, how can I do it?
I'm running windows on my main pc.

Thank you,
Linas

Comment: Why not choose Option 1: Restore factory settings?

Comment: That does nothing.

Comment: So flash the phone! And it will be simple for us to help you if you mind detailing what exactly you did to the phone.

Comment: I tried to flash and no luck. I don't know what happened to the phone it restarted and this now comes up.

Comment: Well if factory reset doesn't help, and you can't flash stock firmware, than is dead.

Comment: That's what I thought. The question was can I use sdcard for booting?

Comment: I downloaded the software from huawei's site copied it to and sdcard. Booted into recovery and flashed the UPDATE.APP.

Comment: You cannot boot from sdcard, Android doesn't allow that under any circumstances.

Comment: @acejavelin, actually you can. according to this: http://linux-sunxi.org/Boot_Android_from_SdCard

Comment: @LinasNikiperavicius UPDATE.APP can't be flashed through recovery! The only way is either by force-flashing (volume up + down buttons) for when in bootloop or in settings > about > update, in case the phone boots normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I was not possible until I discovere this site. You can boot Android from an SD Card. The complete guide is from [here](http://linux-sunxi.org/Boot_Android_from_SdCard). I warn you, you'll have headache if you're not familiar with commands :D :D

Comment: This still requires a bootable device, the boot image will sit on the device and passes control to the SD card, you need complete device access (bootloader, root, block level read/writes)... My guess in looking at this is its Gingerbread to ICS era and there are security measures in KitKat and newer Android OS versions that could make this difficult and in devices based on Lollipop or Marshmallow additional security implementation in the bootloader will likely make this impossible.

Comment: indeed, so it is not that impossible as you said though

Comment: True, but on this device which shipped with KitKat and is currently on factory Lollipop, it is impossible, especially since it isn't bootable and there is no access to the current partitions.